# iOS plist saving across update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plist

I have a plist in my app that is already in appstore. Users can make saves/changes in that plist. It is stored in the apps Documents folder.

Will this plist remain if the users update to a new version, or is it returned to default (what is sent in the app bundle)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you coded the app... But if your app is set up to only load the plist into your bundle when there is not currently a plist than it shouldn't be over-written.

I had an update come out today and my plist data was still there...

This is how a plist should be copied into the bundle from your resources folder the first time the user launches the app: (*Note, if the user deletes the app then downloads the update the data will be gone)

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourPLIST" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user-updated plist in Documents should be safe: data in the app bundle (such as the resource path) gets overwritten, but data in the user's Documents and Library folders isn't. This is why you can update apps and still have your documents and preferences intact.

Note that it's important to use the standard iOS calls to get the path to the Document's folder, not to (for example) hard-code the path.

See also:

[iphone: preserve user data against app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778284/iphone-preserve-user-data-against-app-update)

[app data loss on version upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459216/app-data-loss-on-version-upgrade)